generate SQLModel from datamodel-code-generation
I am using datamodel-code-generation to generate python bindings from an OpenAPI spec. While it can generate pydantic models, I really need SQLModel so that I can store it in a DB. Some of the objects are tables: specifying just a --base-model does not generate it in the form of (e.g) Customer(SQLModel, Table=true) (Table=true is missing).
Is there a way to get the package to generate SQLModel, or alternate ways of doing this?

SQLModel is still a fairly new and immature library, so I would not expect this to exist. Your best bet is probably writing a custom script that wraps datamodel-code-generator and then processes the result (would just replacing (SQLModel) with (SQLModel, table=True) be sufficient?)

@M.O. Most likely not as you would have to additionally define the relationships and the ID-fields. I also don't know any packages for this yet.

@Siddharth Ram Recently, a colleague of mine wrote some post-processing to generate such SQLModel classes using datamodel-code-generator - but it's very specific to our use-case. However, if you need some inspiration you could take a look at parser.py and sqlparser.py here.
